# What does three dots(...) means in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does `...` mean in this code?

**The code is:**

```
  if (state.isSubmitting) ...[
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                const LinearProgressIndicator(value: null),
              ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists), the **Spread Operator(...)** provides a concise way to insert multiple values into a collection.
For instance, let's say there is a List:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
```

and you want to add this list to another list, you use spread operator

```
var anotherList = [0, 1, ...list];
```

Comment: So what does `...` mean in the OP ?

Answer (score 4):

In `Dart` (...) Tripple dot is called as `spread operator` which is basically introduced in `Dart 2.3`.

Well, `spread operator` provides an easy way to insert multiple-element into a collection

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var numbers2 = [0, ...list];
print(numbers2);
```

And the `spread operator` is also a null aware one, for example

```
var numbers;
var numbers2 = [0, ...?list];
print(numbers2);
```

for more and conscious explanation you can refer to this link [Dart spread operstor](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/spread-collections/feature-specification.md)