# What the ... does on the array, like: List = [... item]

Tags: arrays, flutter, arraylist, operators

I've seen  this code a lot and
I really don't know what the ... does on an Array.
I've seen on this situation.
 `list = [... item];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does three dots(...) means in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294046/what-does-three-dots-means-in-flutter/69294079#69294079)

Comment: Yes, thats just perfect. Thanks man.